# Multiple value to select field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want the user to click the select box and when have selected any option redirect to `index.php?id={variableId}&itemId={secondVariableId}`

Like:

```
<select name="select">
<option value="id=1&itemId=2">One</option>
<option value="id=1&itemId=3">One</option>
<option value="id=2&itemId=1">One</option>
[...]
</select>
```

But, I can not imagine where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select name="select" onchange="window.location='index.php?' + this.value;">
    <option value="default">- select -</option>
    <option value="id=1&itemId=2">One</option>
    <option value="id=1&itemId=3">One</option>
    <option value="id=2&itemId=1">One</option>
    [...]
</select>
```

Comment: Well, I have done this, the problem is, how to get two values where id is one variable and itemId another `
<option value="id=2&itemId=1">One</option>`?

Comment: You can get the variables in PHP using `$_GET["id"]` and `$_GET["itemId"]`.

Comment: Worked well, but my url appear: `Itemid=48%26id%3D3`, however, my PHP work fine =)
(I know about the GETs =P)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "onChange()" function, but does not work properly in some versions of IE, as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want (if i'm understanding correctly and assuming jquery is being used).

```
$("select").on("change", function() {
  window.location = 'index.php?' + $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: you should use select[name="select"] to specify your selector or you may have problems at some cases.

Comment: @GuilhermeDaviddaCosta, Yes. My example assumes the user has knowledge of the correct way to use jquery selectors.

Comment: So, assuming that you just didn't want to spend 1 second to write a better selector. Then you should write at the end of your answer about what you've assumed, so someone that don't have the proper knowledge get confused.

Comment: Since the OP didn't spend extra time including the entire markup of his page, nor did he ask about selectors, it wasn't necessary.  If you're going to be nit-picky, $("select[name='select']") is just as bad considering you don't know what other markup is on the page.  You're comments aren't helpful.

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is add the option multiple=yes to your select tag.  When this is posted back, it will be in an array.  Here's a good sample that you can test with: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_select_multiple

Answer (score 1):

Hiya this might help: **sample demo** http://jsfiddle.net/5NCQg/34/

**Jquery COde**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var url = "http://forum.jquery.com?" // in this case your URL
$("select#foobar").change(function() {
        alert('change');

        url= url + $(this).val();
        alert(url);

        window.location = url;


  });
});​
```

**HTML**

```
<form id="temp1">
    <select id="foobar">
        <option value="nothing"> --select-- </option>
    <option value="id=foo&itemid=bar"> click1 </option>
    <option value="id=foo&itemid=bar"> click2 </option> 
    </select>
</form>​
```

CHeers!